# When to delete your own question

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions, self-delete

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709576/php-functional-style-light-weight-alternatives-to-the-separation-of-concerns-in), and for whatever reason (probably my fault for not being clear, or asking something too similar to other questions about MVC frameworks), the answers didn't really go in the direction that I was looking for. I expect that to happen with questions on Stack Overflow sometimes, and I accept that.  But now I've got a question that I consider useless. I don't think someone randomly finding the question via google would get any value out of the question's answers, and maybe I'll clarify what I'm looking for and ask the question in a much better way later.

I essentially accepted the answer that was most applicable (though not really what I was looking for) because I enjoy having people actually answer my questions, and wouldn't want to discourage that.

Should I delete the question?  Does deleting my own question cost me / answerers reputation, in which case I'll probably just skip it?  Is deleting and then reasking a similar question a bad way to go?  Should I try to completely edit the question into essentially a new (if somewhat similar) question in order to try to get a more effective answer?

Comment: I doubt you can delete it. Two answers with upvotes means that the question has value for the community.

Comment: Still has a delete button.  Presumably it isn't a vestigal delete button.

Comment: Click it! It will tell you that you can't delete it.

Comment: Ah, right you are, it is indeed a vestigial delete button, like the appendix.  Though it does show the reasons why the question can't be deleted, so I suppose it still has a little bit of informational use still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you should edit the question **to drive future answers in a different direction**. You will make the current answers either wrong or irrelevant. Users answered the question *as posed* and you accepted an answer.

If you can see where you went wrong with the question, ask it again in a way that is not a duplicate and will solicit different answers. If it helps, reference your original question and clarify why you should expect different answers this time around.

*Also, I don't think you can delete your original question, once it has been answered. But, if you could, you would lose any rep gains/losses from the question after the next reputation re-calc.*

Comment: Regarding rep gains/losses -- My understanding is that upon the next recalc you lose *gains* from deleted posts, but you keep the losses. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/foo/5222#5222

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

It'd have to be a pretty poor question (and associated answers) to be of no possible value to someone finding it via Google (misleading, dangerous, etc).  I wouldn't significantly edit the existing question; rather use it as a learning experience and ask another, more tightly-focussed question.