# If I delete an answer, do I lose reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

If I delete my answer with some up votes, do I lose the reputation?
Or, if I delete an answer with down votes, is negative reputation negated?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the past you would lose (or regain) all reputation due to a post being deleted, but this has changed in March 2012.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/

There is now an exception to the rule that votes are reversed at the time of deletion and that is to reward content of "lasting value" as follows:

> **First**, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets
> deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days
>
> In fast-changing professions, there should be no shame in contributing
> valuable information just because it eventually goes out of date – and
> there shouldn’t be a penalty for deleting it when it does. Naturally,
> editing to bring an answer up-to-date is preferable – but if someone
> else already posted a good answer with current information, you should
> be able to remove yours and keep the reward for the time it was
> useful.

Comment: So as a case in point, @you's [answer above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90064/165931) gained reputation but is now incorrect. It could be deleted without losing the reputation that was gained. I could have edited it and replaced about every word but instead chose to answer separately.

Comment: But, BЈовић, to [allow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) YOU to delete their own answer, first the "Accepted" checkmark must be taken away from it...

Comment: Votes indicate popularity, which does not directly indicate valuable information. Not often, but sometimes popular answers can be wrong, harmful, or besides the point.

Comment: Just to make it clear: do you keep the reputation if it has a score of 3 or greater **_AND_** was visible on the site for at least 60 days, or if it has a score of 3 or greater **_OR_** was visible on the site for at least 60 days?