# Delete or answer to my own question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Recently I am struggling with windows-8 (maybe I don't know how to search things for it) and that led me to Stack Overflow more times than usual. To make questions, unfortunately. Some of them I realized that are too specific after I find the solution. So, I usually delete them. Although on meta we have a good post with [good motives to delete your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88346/under-which-circumstances-should-i-delete-my-own-question-or-answer) in my scenario I didn't find a duplicate of my question and I believe that my question has value and it makes sense for people that are starting with windows-8/xaml/wpf/and technologies related.

Recently [I have made this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213849/scrollviewer-doesnt-scroll-with-touch) and today I found the solution. It turns out that it was a combo of solutions that I found in the Internet AND the rest of the layout (that is not mentioned in the question) that was causing all this mess.

So, in scenarios that I might find the question useful (although it has 0 upvotes) but the answer is too specific how should I proceed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Post the answer.

You never know who might be having the same problem with the same solution.

It might be that others will add other valuable answers to the question as well.

Comment: I understand that point of view and most of my self-answers were done based on that. However, if I don't have feedback about the "usefullness" of that solution maybe it is better to work for a cleaner Stack Overflow? Also, if I answer should I accept as soon as I can or wait a little time so more people can see it and maybe provide a better solution?

Comment: Having an answer is better than not having it... And you can always wait a few days (or more) before accepting. There is no requirement to accept, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. Already answered. Probably I shouldn't have deleted some questions.